# How to find out all function and its parameter in a .dll file

Tags: packages, librarylink

### Cross post [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1178215?p_p_auth=tCmn2TZ5)

Since `LibraryFunctionLoad` can load a function from `.dll` file like

```
fun = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo", "demo_I_I", {Integer}, Integer]
```

Then you can use function `fun` in *Mathematica*. And I can know this function `demo_I_I` from this `.dll`
LibraryFunctionInformation[fun]

```
{"ReturnType" -> Integer, "ArgumentTypes" -> {Integer},"File" -> 
  "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\11.1zh\\SystemFiles\\Links\\LibraryLink\\\
LibraryResources\\Windows-x86-64\\demo.dll", "Function" -> "demo_I_I"}
```

But how to know which function can be loaded in this `.dll` file.And how to know its form of parameter?

Comment: This is a question about dynamic libraries, not about Mathematica. In any case, finding the names of the exported functions is easy (use tools like dumpbin on Windows or nm on Unix). Determining the signature is not possible in general, although demangling could be done in  the (not common) special case of C++ exports.